# How to find minimum value( doesn't work ) The Reason?

Tags: java, eclipse, logic

I know how to make the code work by making the minvalue to be a very large number .
I just need to know the logic behind eclipse not running this program

```
public static int getMinValue(int[] ary)
    {
        int Minvalue = 0;
        random(ary);
    for (int i=ary.length-1; i >=0 ;i-- )
    {
            if (ary[i]<ary[i--])
                 Minvalue=ary[i];
    }
        System.out.printf("Minvalue:%d",Minvalue);
        return Minvalue;


    }
```

Comment: *I just need to know the logic behind eclipse not running this program*  because it's not in a main method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will simply do like this:

```
public static int getMinValue(int[] ary) {
    random(ary);
    if (ary.length > 0) {
        int minValue = ary[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < ary.length; i++) {
            if (ary[i] < minValue)
                minValue = ary[i];
        }
        System.out.printf("Minvalue:%d", minValue);
        return minValue;
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("The array must contain at least one element");
}
```

The problems in your implementation are that you should compare the element of your array with the `minValue` variable that in the `for-statement` contains the minimum value between the values that you have already read. Moreover you use `i--` that changes the guard evaluation of the `for-statement`.
Another thing to notice is that, at least for me, is more natural to have an "incrementing" `for-loop` starting from `0` to `ary.length` rather than a "decrementing" one ...

Answer (score 0):

1) you need to sort the int array , either using the Arrays.sort(ary) or custom sorting algorithm like Bubble Sort , quicksort etc..

2) Than access the first index ary[0] for minimum value or ary[ary.length-1] or max value

That's it.

```
public static int getMinValue (int[] ary) throws Exception 
{
    int Minvalue = 0;

    if (ary.length > 0 )
    {
     Arrays.sort(ary);

     Minvalue = ary[0];

     return Minvalue;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception ("Empty array");
    }


}//end method
```

Comment: You can do it this way; not sure you NEED to sort it in this case although, there are situations where that is preferable, it depends what you will be using the array for next.

Comment: You definitely do *not* need to sort the array to find the minimum value.  In fact, if that's all you want to do, this is needlessly inefficient.  Best case efficiency of Arrays.sort is O(n*log(n)), linear search is O(n).  Also, I wouldn't expect finding the minimum value of an array to alter the array, which this algorithm does.

Answer (score -2):

It isn't working because you only check the values in the array that occur in the index position prior to where you check.

If you want to find the minimum value you need to check all possible values within the array.

```
for (int i=ary.length-1; i >=0 ;i-- )
{
    Boolean flag = false; //this stays false in the case of lowest min value
    for (int z=ary.length-1; z>=0; z--)
        if (ary[i]>ary[z]) 
             flag = true; //flag is true if any array value is greater than current

    if(!flag)
    {
        minValue = ary[I];
        break; //just to avoid useless checks
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) You don't need to check every possible combination of elements.  A single `for` loop pass through the array will do. 2) your `z` variable starts at the end of the array, and goes *up* from there, throwing an exception. 3) `flag` is never reset, so if the first value you look at isn't the minimum, you'll never find it.

Comment: Yeah was kind of tired writing this, been up all night trying to work on my dijkstra's algorithm. Fixed the issues to avoid any misconceptions